# Error:(19) Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: android

I have got the above error in the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android.justjava.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="QUANTITY"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>
    <TextView
        android:="@+id/quantity_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Commander"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm unable to figure out what's wrong. Could anybody please help me on this?

Comment: Your XML seems OK. You may want to provide more error message.

Comment: It is ok. You can clean your project

Comment: Thank you Nabin, find bellow more error:

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\fujistsu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: As nabin said, your xml is good. post your complete error log

Answer (score 1):

There is no attribute name in the first line of your second TextView.

```
<TextView
        android:="@+id/quantity_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>
```

I guess you need to add id:

```
android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
```

Comment: I don't see any error in that line. Though you might get a warning to use a string resource rather than a Hardcoded string. That's not an error.

Comment: Ok Bob, it works! as you said it was the android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view" that i used instead of the android:="@+id/quantity_text_view" one. thank you!

Comment: If it's working, would you please upvote/ mark as correct?